# How do I set the Decimal precision everywhere in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I'm working with Elixir's Decimal module:

https://hexdocs.pm/decimal/readme.html

I've written my own macro to update the precision:

```
defmodule Mars.Decimal do
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      require Decimal

      %{Decimal.Context.get() | precision: 2}
      |> Decimal.Context.set()

  end
end
```

Questions:

This doesn't seem to affect the precision at all. How do I set the precision globally?

Currently, Decimal doesn't equate mixed precision, i.e. `Decimal.new(1) != Decimal.new("1.0")`.

I'm hoping if I can set the precision to be fixed everywhere, I can fix this.

As an added question; I'm trying to do this for currency, so it's always 2 decimal places. The Decimal module's precision only sets the total accuracy (i.e. up to 2 digits, no matter the side of the `.`, i.e. 3456.123 -> 3500). If there's a cleaner way of handling monetary figures in Elixir, please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this post https://elixirforum.com/t/how-to-set-default-decimal-precision/40404, the precision needs to be set **in each process where you want it to be in effect**.  Pasting `Decimal.Context.set(%Decimal.Context{Decimal.Context.get() | precision: 2})` into an `iex` session, for example, *does* affect all subsequent calculations that take place in `iex` because `iex` runs in its own process.

However, that doesn't help back in the "real world" where your app may execute in lots of different (and unknown) processes.  I think the docs could benefit from fleshing out a couple examples for your particular use case.

Given the way `Decimal` stores its settings in a process dictionary, you would need to isolate all your computations into a single process, e.g. in a `GenServer`. Then your interactions with it would make calls to that specific process where the context had been set to exactly a precision of 2 decimal places.

Here is an example `GenServer` that sets up a decimal precision of 2:

```
defmodule Foo.Precision2 do
  use GenServer

  def start_link(opts \\ []) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, opts, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def init(state) do
    Decimal.Context.set(%Decimal.Context{Decimal.Context.get() | precision: 2})
    {:ok, state}
  end

  def handle_call({:div, x, y}, _from, state) do
    result = Decimal.div(x, y)
    {:reply, result, state}
  end

  def div(x, y) do
    GenServer.call(__MODULE__, {:div, x, y})
  end
end
```

Then you'd need to start this up with your app, e.g. inside `application.ex`:

```
defmodule Foo.Application do
  @moduledoc false

  use Application

  @impl true
  def start(_type, _args) do=
    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: Foo.Supervisor]

    Supervisor.start_link(
      [
        {Foo.Precision2, []}
      ],
      opts
    )
  end
end
```

And then finally, you could route calls to the `GenServer`'s client functions, e.g.

```
iex> Foo.Precision2.div(100,3)
#Decimal<33>
```

Admittedly, this feels like an absurd amount of setup to support a fairly straight-forward use-case (and there are surely cleaner ways to implement this), but it seems to work.  One advantage of this approach might be that you could maintain multiple contexts with specific settings for each.

Comment: I agree, this is a bit awkward. I think I will fork the Decimal module to get it to do what I need. Thanks for your help!